# Extremum of function $2x^2-y^2-6x$ under condition $x^2+y^2 \le 9$

Tags: optimization

Find extremum of function $z(x,y) = 2x^2-y^2-6x$ under condition $A(x,y) = x^2+y^2 \le 9$. How can we manage when the condition is given by inequality? I only know that Lagrange multiplier works with condition given by equality.

Comment: You can introduce a _slack variable_ $w\ge 0$, which changes the condition to $x^2+y^2+w=9$

Comment: You could first find all interior extrema, where the constraint is not binding. And then all extrema on the boundary, that is, where the constraint is $x^2+y^2=9$.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2-6x$$ the you will get $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=4x-6$$ 
and
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=-2y$$
we get $$x=\frac{3}{2},y=0$$
and then you Can calculate the extrema on the curve $x^2+y^2=9$ so you will have
$$f(x,\pm\sqrt{9-x^2})=2x^2-(9-x^2)-6x$$
Can you finish?
$$f'(x,\pm\sqrt{9-x^2})=6x-6$$

Comment: $(x,y)=(\frac{3}{2},0)$ is not an extremum. It's a saddle point.

Comment: ok, if you know this, why don't you prove this?

Comment: This method is also missing the extremum $(x,y)=(-3,0)$, the constrained maximum, because of the parametrization $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$. Now I see this problem is full of traps.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=-3$ and $y=0$ we obtain a value $36$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that $$2x^2-y^2-6x\leq36$$ and since
$$36\geq3(x^2+y^2)+9,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$2x^2-y^2-6x\leq3(x^2+y^2)+9$$ or
$4(x+3)^2+4y^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

For $x=1$ and $y=2\sqrt2$ we get a value $-12$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$2x^2-y^2-6x\geq-12$$ and since $$12\geq3+x^2+y^2,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$2x^2-y^2-6x+3+x^2+y^2\geq0$$ or$$3(x-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done!